# How to send AT commands to serial port through C - Linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, at-command

Of course there is `termios.h`, but here I am talking about `AT` commands. I want them to get *executed*.

How to send AT commands to serial port through `C` in Linux *so that they get executed*?

Comment: just send these commands as text.

Comment: Devices are files in *nix. Try just opening the serial port as a file and read/write from/to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serial port reading and writing with C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452359/serial-port-reading-and-writing-with-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this brief example (it works):

```
struct termios options;
int fd;

fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if (fd < 0)
{
    printf("Error opening serial port\n");
    exit(1);
}

bzero(&options, sizeof(options));
options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | IGNPAR;
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

if (write(fd, "ATZ\r", 4) < 4)
{
    printf("Write error - %s \n", strerror(errno));
    exit (1);
}

// read back for OK or KO then do your stuff...
```

Comment: thanks, I was wondering how does port distinguish between commands and text.

Comment: It's Hayes method for communicating with modems. It distinguishes by format that is the AT command prepended. Check link in answer below about Serial_Programming

Comment: @DaneBalia Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this, might help:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Linux

Also the definitive guide for Advanced Linux Programming in C
http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/

Comment: And to learn a bit more about AT commands, by all means read the V.250 standard, http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en.